# Retrieving return value from stored procedure in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2012, frameworks

I tried but I failed so hard on this one. So I try to get some help from you.

I have a stored procedure with no input parameters, but I like to get some result values back (3 values as int).

I created the stored procedure and added it to the EF but I get a single integer back, instead of the 3 values.

My stored procedure code:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT Name FROM sys.objects 
               WHERE OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.ExtendUncanceldContracts'))
    EXECUTE sp_executesql N'CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.ExtendUncanceldContracts AS BEGIN SELECT 1 AS ID END'; 
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.ExtendUncanceldContracts
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        /* Do a lot of stuff */ 
        EXEC AnotherStoredProcedure @AnId

        DECLARE @tt INT; 
        DECLARE @ur INT;
        DECLARE @ufr INT;

        SET @tt = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #UpdateTableTemp)
        SET @ur = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #UpdateTable1Temp)
        SET @ufr = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #UpdateTable2Temp)

        DECLARE @tablevar AS TABLE (tt INT, ur INT, ufr INT)

        INSERT INTO @tablevar (tt, ur, ufr) 
        VALUES (@tt, @ur, @ufr)

        SELECT * FROM @tablevar
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        DECLARE @ErrorState INT = ERROR_STATE(),
                @ErrorSeverity INT = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
                @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000) = ISNULL(ERROR_PROCEDURE(),'<noProcName>');

        RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage,@ErrorSeverity,@ErrorState);
    END CATCH
END
```

My C# code

```
public bool ExtendUncanceldContracts()
{
    try
    {
        var res = (from o in ctx.ExtendUncanceldContracts()
                   select o).ToList();
        ctx.SaveChanges();
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("Some error Text");
    }
}
```

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using, that stored procedure is product specific.

Comment: Have you tried 'SELECT tt, ur, ufr FROM @tablevar' rather than just 'SELECT *', I seem to recall issues at times returns all columns

Comment: Did it but it made no difference

Comment: So the problem is still pending. I only get the value from the Stored Procedure "AnotherStoredProcedure". All other return values will be "ignored". Any idea how I can solve that?